# How to generate full qmd file from child files?

Tags: r-markdown, quarto

I have a quarto file with several child documents. I can render them just fine.
But I would like to generate a single qmd file that contains the full document.
So basically I need some kind of qmd to qmd converter. Is there a way to do that?

Sections like this insert the children:

````
```{r}
#| label = "child1",
#| eval = TRUE,
#| child = "child1.qmd"
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Seems noone has a "nice" solution. So here is a hack to put things together "manually".
It finds the code blocks with a child defined and replaces that code box with the text from the references child.

````
merge_children <- function(file, path_prefix, outpath, child_pattern = "[[:blank:]]*#\\|[[:blank:]]*child[[:blank:]]*=.*,+[[:blank:]]*", child_capture = "[[:blank:]]*#\\|[[:blank:]]*child.*=.*,+[[:blank:]]*"){
  # read file
  txt <- readLines(file)
  
  # find children
  child_defs <-  txt %>% grep(child_pattern,.)
  
  
  # find children paths
  child_paths <-  map_chr(child_defs,  function(x){
                                                    txt[x] %>% 
                                                    gsub(child_capture,"\\1", .) %>% 
                                                    gsub('.*\\"(.*)\\".*',"\\1", .)
                                                  }
                         )

  
  if(length(child_paths)==0){
    
    writeLines(txt, outpath)
    return(message("No children found. Will just copy file."))
    }
  
  
  child_paths <- paste0(path_prefix, child_paths)
  
  
  #find start and end of relevant code sections
  code_start <- txt %>% grep("^[[:blank:]]*```\\{r.*",.)
  code_end   <- txt %>% grep("^[[:blank:]]*```[[:blank:]]*$",.)
  
  # read children
  txt_children <- map(child_paths, readLines)
  
  indeces <- sort(c(1, code_start, code_end+1))
  
  txt_split <- split(txt, rep(seq(indeces), diff(c(indeces, length(txt)+1))))
  
  has_child <-  map_lgl(txt_split, ~any(grepl(child_pattern,..1))) %>% as.vector %>% which
  
  # replace children
  if(length(has_child) != length(txt_children)) stop("children replacement indeces not equal to amount of children")
  
  txt_split[has_child] <- txt_children
  
  # put back together
  txt_new <- txt_split %>% unlist()

  
  writeLines(txt_new, outpath)
  
}
````